# How can I write a query to match groups of records

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is a puzzling SQL task. I'd like to do it with a query instead of stepping through with a cursor and doing it the "hard way".

If I have two tables TableA and TableB each with a grouping column as below:

```
TableA             TableB
-------------      -------------
id     group       id     group
------ ------      ------ ------
1      D           1      X
2      D           2      X
3      D           3      Y
4      D           4      Y
4      E           5      Y
5      E           5      Z
5      F           6      Z
```

Note the group names are *not* the same name.

I want to know if a given TableB group is comprised entirely of IDs which are also grouped together in any group in TableA. The TableA group can have more IDs than the TableB group, so long as it has all of the same IDs as the TableB group. IDs can be in more than one group in either table.

From the tables above, I should find out that group X from TableB matches a group in TableA, but groups Y and Z do not.

I've tried many different queries, subqueries, recursive CTEs. I've only ended up with wrong results and headaches. The real dataset is significantly larger, so performance should be considered a factor too. Unfortunately, that means the cross-join solution proposed in an answer below won't work.

Is this even possible with SQL?

Comment: I ended up just going with a cursor-based solution. (Sometimes, cursors are the best answer!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea for this query is to consider every group to every other group.  Then count the number of times that the ids match.  This involves a `cross join` to generate all the group pairs, then some joins and aggregation:

```
select b.group, a.group
from (select group, count(*) as cnt b group by group) bg cross join
     (select distinct group a) ag left join
     b
     on b.group = bg.group left join
     a
     on a.group = ag.group and a.id = b.id
group by bg.group, ag.group, bg.cnt
having bg.cnt = count(a.id)
```

Comment: Thanks. Logically this works. Unfortunately, my real dataset is too big for the cross join to be viable. Very clever solution, though. I'll accept if no one else has a more performant approach.

Answer (score 0):

This query could give the answer.

```
SELECT B.[group] 
FROM 
   TableB B
   FULL JOIN TableA A ON B.id = A.id
GROUP BY 
   B.[group]
HAVING 
   COUNT(DISTINCT A.[group]) = 1
```